# Pythonic way to create a variable that will later be an object?

Tags: python

When creating a variable that will later have some other string assigned to it, it's typical to do this:

```
my_string = ""
```

for an array:

```
my_array = []
```

and so on.  For a variable that will later have an object assigned to it, you could assign it anything to start out with, but what is the pythonic thing to do?  It seems like a waste to create an instance of the class with 'empty' things passed to it.

Comment: How about `None`?

Comment: Assign `None` to it.

Comment: Do you even need to create this variable ahead of time?  Python doesn't require it.  Assigning it some 'standby' value like `None` might make some other checking or argument passing easier,

Answer (score 1):

You can use `None`.

Or, if there is a chance that you'll want to be comparing it something that could possibly be `None` and you want to know the difference, you can use `object()`. While you still have to create an unused object, the benefit is that `my_object is object` will only return `True` if `my_object` has not been updated.

Answer (score 1):

In both your examples cases, strings and lists, that is commonly to set up each to add to the empty object. Strings support concatenation and lists support myriad of functions on an empty lists.

Here is an example for strings where the logic would break if you did not have `s=''`:

```
>>> vowels='aeiou'
>>> s=''
>>> for ch in 'This is a longer string':
...   if ch in vowels: s+=ch
... 
>>> s
'iiaoei'
```

If you have an object that supports building on or adding to the empty thing, you can call the constructor.

```
foo()   # object foo that I will add to later...
```

Or, classic Python example:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c=Counter()
>>> c=Counter()
>>> c+=Counter('123')
>>> c+=Counter('11222233333')
>>> c
Counter({'3': 6, '2': 5, '1': 3})
```

So:

1. **First case:** *Create an object if you are going to add to it. Call the constructor like `Counter()` or the shortcut constructor like `[]`*
2. **Second case:** If you want to send a signal that your object is ['truthy' or 'falsy'](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html) for some logic shortcut later in the program (where your object either get filled with an object or tested) use `True` or `False` for this. Or, if you are sending a signal that this object is empty or null or not yet dealt with, use `None`.

If it is not 'first case' or 'second case' above -- Then **don't**. You are obfuscating.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about constructing unnecessary objects, you could use `None`. Since it is a singleton(i.e there is only one copy of `None` per Python interpreter), you wouldn't be wasting time and memory creating a full fledged object. Here is an example usage:

```
>>> user_input = None
>>> try:
    user_input = int(input('Enter a digit: '))
except ValueError:
    user_input = 'failed'


Enter a digit: abjkjsds
>>> user_input
'failed'
>>>
```

Since `True` and `False` are also singletons,  you could use them to have the same effect. There may be cases where is is more appropriate to use a boolean value rather than simply using `None`.